# How to remove NAN in index in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

[Can anybody tell me how to remove NAN VALUES in index column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EsJi.png)

Comment: df.reset_index(inplace=True)

Comment: i did that but it adds a new index column

Comment: `df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)`

Comment: Do you want remove the rows or replace the index?

Comment: @-gyx-hh thanks alot

Comment: @gyx-hh,  this is what OP's requirement is +1

Comment: @cyberman, i have simulated the same index environment and placed my answer  with the test if you see that helps you you can upvote or mark it as accepted so it will be removed from the answered Queue!

Answer (score 6):

There are couple ways to do it..

## if you are using python recent versions.

`df.loc[df.index.dropna()]`

## if  you are using  pandas version `>= 0.20.0` you can:

```
df[df.index.notnull()]
```

## if you are using older versions, you can try..

```
df[pd.notnull(df.index)]
```

OR

```
df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

As suggested by @gyx-hh

```
 df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

Example Set:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], 'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'], 'val': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}, index=[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan])
>>> df
     Date Name  val
NaN     0    A    0
NaN     1    B    1
NaN     2    C    2
NaN     0    A    3
NaN     1    B    4
NaN     2    C    5
```

a)

```
>>> df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
>>> df
   Date Name  val
0     0    A    0
1     1    B    1
2     2    C    2
3     0    A    3
4     1    B    4
5     2    C    5
```

Note : i have not kept other answers as such `df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)` because it will modify your original dataFrame  as we are using `inplace=True`.